# Client-server two way communication

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I wrote simple client serwer, but unfortunately, I did it so chaotic and poorly that I decided to write everything from scratch. I want to write to communicate in both directions with the ability to disconnect and connect a new client. It means the client or the server sends a message and an appropriate one reads it. At the beginning all works but when i want to close client i get two errors:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed readSocketData()
java.net.SocketException: Socket closedwriteData(String data)
```

Of course I understand what those errors means , but I do not understand why they show up because i have a while loop in which i check if the client is connected. Later when i try to connect a new client everything is falling apart.
I wrote 3 classes client, server and communication. Client and server inherits from communication (methods for opening and reading data streams). It all looks like that:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server extends Communication{

ServerSocket serverSocket;
Socket listener;
boolean listenerLife;

public Server(int port) {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void startListener(){

    while (true){
        try {
            listener = serverSocket.accept();
            listenerLife = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        openWriter(listener);
        openReader(listener);
        writeServerDataThread();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                readData();
            }
        }).start();
    }

}

public void writeServerDataThread(){
    openLocalReader();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true){
                String data = readLocalData();
                writeData(data);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


public void readData(){
    while (listenerLife){
        String data = readSocketData();

        if("exit".equals(data) || data == null){
            try {
                listenerLife = false;
                listener.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(data);
        }

    }
}



public void writeData(String data){
    try {
        writer.writeBytes(data + '\n');
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    server.startListener();


}
}
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client extends Communication{

Socket clientSocket;
boolean clientLive;

public Client(String hostName, int port) {

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
        clientLive = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + "Client(String hostName, int port)");
    }

}

public boolean closeConnection(String data){
    if("exit".equals(data) || data == null){
        try {
            writeData("Zamykam klienta");
            clientSocket.close();
            clientLive = false;
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "closeConnection(String data)");
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void readClientData(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            openLocalReader();
            while (!clientSocket.isClosed()){
                String data = readLocalData();

                if(closeConnection(data)){
                    writeData(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

public void readServerDataThread(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while (!clientSocket.isClosed()){
                String data = readSocketData();

                if(closeConnection(data)){
                    System.out.println(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

public void writeData(String data){
    try {
        writer.writeBytes(data + '\n');
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + "writeData(String data)");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Client client = new Client("localhost", 8080);
    client.openReader(client.clientSocket);
    client.openWriter(client.clientSocket);
    client.readServerDataThread();

    client.readClientData();


}
}
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Communication {

BufferedReader reader;
BufferedReader localReader;
DataOutputStream writer;

public void openReader(Socket incomingSocket){

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(incomingSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void openWriter(Socket incomingSocket){

    try {
        writer = new DataOutputStream(incomingSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void openLocalReader(){
    localReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}

public String readLocalData(){
    String data = null;

    try {
        data = localReader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + " readLocalData()");
    }
    return data;
}

public String readSocketData(){
    String data = null;

    try {
        data = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + " readSocketData()");
    }
    return data;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed readSocketData()
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed writeData(String data)
```

> Of course I understand what those errors means

They mean you closed the socket and continued to use it.

> but I do not understand why they show up because i have a while loop in which i check if the client is connected.

No you don't. You have a `while` loop in which you check if the client *socket* is still *open,* which isn't the same thing at all ... but in any case that doesn't prevent you from using a closed socket *inside* the loop, for example after you close it in `closeConnection()`, whose return value being back to front from what it should be is doubtless causing confusion, and which is called by two threads as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't get it. How should i do?